# How would I run the same application separately

Tags: node.js, angular, mongodb, docker

I want to create a service for companies, but instead of running the application in the same container for each company I would like to create a "separate" container for each company.

For example:

1. google.serviceapplication.com
2. bing.serviceapplication.com

I'd like to run the same version of the angular application in each "container" but each company will need their own MongoDB Database.

Is there an existing solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

We use Spring Boot and change the application.properties for the different companies.

The Backend / Frontend Code is the same.

If you share some infos about the Backend i could give a more datailed answer.

Comment: It's still an ongoing project, but the backend will be a separate API made with the NestJS framework. The frontend will run on a simple express server.

Answer (score 0):

First you have to make decision what software you will use to manage your containers in production.
Well known options is Kubernetes or Docker Swarm.
If you will use Kubernetes then namespaces is answer to your problem. You just create different namespace for each deployment you want.